# Use cases for key-in-client encrypted cloud storage

Tags: encryption, key, cloud, storage

We're advocating for the use of key-in-client encrypted cloud storage. The benefit would seem obvious, in that the operator of the cloud server doesn't have access to the content of the files, but we've been asked to be specific about who is using key-in-client encrypted cloud storage and why.

Comment: Could you give more context to this question since this looks like the architectural decision, that may vary across projects?

Comment: We're a provider of the technology. An investor wants to know who uses key-in-client encrypted storage. It's not an architectural decision,  it's a use case explanation we're looking for.

Comment: The first question should be key-in-client encrypted cloud storage differs from at-rest encryption with a customer-managed key?

I would still argue that this is an architectural decision of the solution team.

Most of the cloud providers that I am aware of are supporting at-rest encrypted storage with customer-managed keys - like Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json or Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-supplied-keys